# Using constants with subtraction with Count function in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose have a schema for Suppliers, Catalogue and Parts and we are trying to figure out what suppliers supply all parts except one.

Would this be the correct query? I'm unsure only because of that `-1` at the end of the last select statement, I am unsure if this valid or not.

```
SELECT S.sid 
FROM SUPPLIER S, CATALOGUE C
WHERE S.sid = C.sid
GROUP BY S.sid
HAVING COUNT(*) = ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PARTS) - 1))
```

Comment: Did you try it? Does it work and give the results you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT c.sid 
FROM CATALOGUE c
GROUP BY c.sid
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) - 1 FROM PARTS)
```

You don't need the `SUPPLIERS` table if you only want the id.

I suppose a catalog could contain the same product multiple times.  If this is possible, then you want `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT c.sid 
FROM CATALOGUE c
GROUP BY c.sid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.<partid>) = (SELECT COUNT(*) - 1 FROM PARTS)
```

`<partid>` refers to whatever column has the part information.

Answer (score 0):

Should be `select count(*) -1`.

But you should also avoid old implicit syntax for join based on where and use explicit join syntax:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SUPPLIER S
INNER JOIN  CATALOGUE C ON S.sid = C.sid
GROUP BY S.sid
HAVING COUNT(*) = (
  SELECT COUNT(*) -1 FROM PARTS
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following one with `distinct` clause :

```
SELECT S.sid 
  FROM SUPPLIER S
  JOIN CATALOGUE C ON S.sid = C.sid
  JOIN PARTS P ON P.id = C.parts_id  
 GROUP BY S.sid
HAVING COUNT(distinct C.parts_id) = COUNT(distinct P.parts_id) - 1
```

Comment: I don't believe there is a `parts_id` column in the table SUPPLIER.

Comment: @forpas yes, `catalogue` seems more logical, thanks.